# Java.Lang.OutOfMemoryError occurs in Async Task with ListView

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, android-asynctask, baseadapter

I'm implementing `ListView` with Custom Adapter that `extends BaseAdapter`. In my app images are downloaded from URLs and then set as bitmap images in `Listview`.

The problem is that after complete downloading of 2 images `java.Lang.OutOfMemoryError` occurs and app crashes. I know this is memory issue but I don't know what steps should I take to avoid this... I worked with compressed images and they worked fine.

Below is my Code for `getView()` of `CustomAdapter` and `doInBackground()` of `AsyncTask`.

Thankx in advance...

Any suggestions will be appreciated..

```
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, final ViewGroup parent) {


      if (convertView == null){          
          convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row, parent, false);  

      }

        img_name = "test" + position;
        image = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
        Log.d("URL", ""+values[position]);
        AsyncTaskRunner runner = new AsyncTaskRunner();
        final int x = (int) getItemId(position);
        runner.execute(values[x] , image , img_name);


      return convertView;
    }
```

**doInBackground(Object... params)**

```
protected ImageView doInBackground(Object... params) {
              //publishProgress("Calculating..."); // Calls onProgressUpdate()
           URL imageURL = null;

           try {
            url = (String) params[0];
            img = (ImageView) params[1];
            name = (String) params[2] + ".png";
            imageURL = new URL(url); 
            Log.d("URL", ""+params[0]);
            }

           catch (MalformedURLException e) {
               e.printStackTrace();
            }

           try {
            HttpURLConnection connection= (HttpURLConnection)imageURL.openConnection();
            connection.setDoInput(true);
            connection.connect();

            InputStream inputStream = connection.getInputStream();

            bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStream);
            resized = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap, 200, 200, true);


           }
           catch (IOException e) {

                e.printStackTrace();
           }

           return img;
          }
```

**OnPostExecute(ImageView result)**

```
  protected void onPostExecute(ImageView result) {
              result.setImageBitmap(resized);
          }
```

Comment: As I said I done this for compressed images...The solutions including Bitmap.Compress(...) and BitmapFactory.Options... So thankx for your solution... But I need to work with larger images...I'm guessing it is something to do with Async Task...

Answer (score 2):

> java.Lang.OutOfMemoryError

**Reason:**

Each process in android is assigned a max heap size which varies from 
device to device.(approx. 16 MB on avg.).And high resolution images when used in application occupies large space of this heap.So when a new instance of the bitmap is created and if total size exceeds the allocated heap size, this is error is thrown by the JVM.

**Solution:**

Android provide a way to handle this problem.Before decoding bitmap we just decode it with `options.inJustDecodeBounds = true.` where options is the instance of `BitmapFactory`. It does not load bitmap into memory but it help us to find the width and height of a bitmap so that we can reduce the height and width according to our device.

Then down-scale your bitmap to a create a smaller sized image which would in turn take up less space on the heap.
Here is the way to do it.

```
BitmapFactory.Options bmpBuffer = new BitmapFactory.Options(); 
bmpBuffer.inSampleSize = 3; 
Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path, bmpBuffer);
```

This would make your bitmaps 1/3 rd of the original size and hence 
would take up 1/3rd space as well.

**Eg.**

```
public static Bitmap decodeSampledBitmapFromResource(Resources res, int resId,
    int reqWidth, int reqHeight) {

  // First decode with inJustDecodeBounds=true to check dimensions
  final BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
  options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;        
  BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res, resId, options);

  // Calculate inSampleSize
  options.inSampleSize = calculateInSampleSize(options, reqWidth, reqHeight);

  // Decode bitmap with inSampleSize set
  options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
  return BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res, resId, options);
}
```

**Method to Calculate sample size:**

```
public static int calculateInSampleSize(
            BitmapFactory.Options options, int reqWidth, int reqHeight) {
    // Raw height and width of image
    final int height = options.outHeight;
    final int width = options.outWidth;
    int inSampleSize = 1;

    if (height > reqHeight || width > reqWidth) {
        if (width > height) {
            inSampleSize = Math.round((float)height / (float)reqHeight);
        } else {
            inSampleSize = Math.round((float)width / (float)reqWidth);
        }
    }
    return inSampleSize;
}
```

**Note:**

One additional thing you can do is use following ,in case there is no other option available. However I want to caution you that it would affect other applications on your device. Hence I would not recommend you to use this.

```
<application
        android:largeHeap="true">
</application>
```

`largeHeap="true"` will allow the application to use more heap if it is available.However your app will spend more time during garbage collection.Other apps on the device might get kicked out of memory.

**CommonsWare** has explained it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18937750/1554935)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Picasso Library](http://square.github.io/picasso/) to download images from a url efficiently besides having more options to resize image size, cache, etc. ..

Answer (score 0):

use this `bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream);`

Comment: This post is being automatically flagged as low quality because it is so short / only code. Would you mind expanding it by adding some text to explain how it solves the problem?